# nginx doesnt see updated static content

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

I'm using docker-compose to set up nginx and node

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - node:node
    volumes_from:
      - node
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl

  node:
    container_name: node
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app
      - ./logs:/usr/src/app/logs
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production

    command: npm run package
```

I have node and nginx share the same volume so that nginx can serve the static content generated by node.

When i update the source code in node. I remove the node container and rebuild it via the below

`docker rm node`

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build -d node`

I can see that the new node container has the updated source code with the proper updated static content

`docker exec -it node bash`

`root@e0cd1b990cd2:/usr/src/app# cat public/style.css`

this shows the updated content i want to see

`.project_detail .owner{color:#ccc;padding:10px}`

However, when i login to the nginx container

`docker exec -it nginx bash`

`root@a459b271e787:/# cat /usr/src/app/public/style.css`

`.project_detail .owner{padding:10px}`

as you can see , nginx is not able to see the newly updated static files served by node - despite the node update.  It however works if i restart the nginx container as well.

Am i doing something wrong? Do i have to restart both nginx and node containers to see the updated content?

Comment: Did you try restarting the nginx container?

Comment: @NehalJWani - i just did . it isnt getting updated

Comment: What happens when you ask both the containers to mount the same host directory?

Comment: i'm sorry , i dont understand - dont they share the same volume already with the host?

Comment: `/usr/src/app` doesn't seem to be shared with the host.

Comment: ahh .. it looks like nginx is still looking at the old node volume and not the new one.. how do i change this?

Comment: Create a directory `app` on the host and mount it on both containers. For example, if the directory is at `/home/user/app`, then it should be present in volumes section as: `/home/user/app:/usr/src/app` for both containers.

Comment: I ended up creating a named volume for static files alone now .. works like a charm :) .. do you want to answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sharing volume of one container with another, share a common directory on the host with both the containers. For example, if the directory is at `/home/user/app`, then it should be present in volumes section like:

```
volumes:
  - /home/user/app:/usr/src/app
```

This should be done for both the containers.

Comment: This will not fix this issue, its just a equal Alternative, beside volume_from becomes less practical in the recent past